# Trouble downloading a zip file from my server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've set up a server endpoint that will zip a folder of files and return the zip file.  On the client-side, I have code that calls the endpoint and saves the downloaded zip file to disk.  All the code runs, but the resultant file is bigger than the zip file on the server and if I try to open the resultant zip file, I get "Windows can't open the file, file is invalid".  What am I doing wrong?

Server code:

```
    [Route("projects/files/download")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromForm] DownloadFileRequest request)
    {       
        string filesPath = ...;
        string zipName = ...;
        if (!Directory.Exists(filesPath)) {`
            return BadRequest("File path not found on server");
        }
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(zipName)) System.IO.File.Delete(zipName);
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filesPath, zipName);
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(zipName);
        FileContentResult zipFile = File(fileBytes, "application/zip", fileName);
        return Ok(zipFile);
    }
```

Client code:

```
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://.../projects/files/download");
    response = client.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), formContent).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)`
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            Stream stream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            string path = ...;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(streamToWriteTo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try commenting out `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`, will it work?

Comment: Also try looking thru notepad at the received file, what is located at its beginning?

Comment: Looking at the file using Notepad, I see that the file is a JSON string that includes the FileContents among other things.  Is it JSON because of my server returning an ObjectResult (return Ok(zipFile);)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the Ok(zipFile), just return the file:

return File(fileBytes, "application/zip", fileName);